# NetSuite: TypeError record.viewCurrentLineItemSubrecord is not a function?

Tags: javascript, netsuite

I'm getting "TypeError record.viewCurrentLineItemSubrecord is not a function" when trying the below code:

```
function saveRecord(){    
    var isChild = nlapiGetFieldValue('parent'); //will be null if parent record
    if(!isChild){     
        var record = nlapiLoadRecord('customer', 177986, {recordmode: 'dynamic'});
        record.selectLineItem('addressbook', 1);
        var subrecord = record.viewCurrentLineItemSubrecord('addressbook', 'addressbookaddress');
        var address = subrecord.getFieldValue('addr1');
        nlapiLogExecution('DEBUG', 'Single Record Test', 'Child Record Address: ' + address);
    }        
    return true;
}
```

Ultimately, I'm trying to update the billing address of all child records when the parent record is saved, hence the above "saveRecord" function. Before I get too complicated, I wanted to try the code from "Sample Scripts for Address Subrecords" page in the Help Center. My code is nearly identical to the Help Center's code, so why isn't it working? What am I missing?

Comment: in which script context are you running the above script?

Comment: I made it a Client script since I wanted it to run when one of my users saves a customer record.

Comment: Interesting, so perhaps a Client script wasn't the right route for what I want to do. So should I make it a User Event script?

Comment: unfortunately, it works on server side only, poor documentation of net suite

Comment: Okay, this is really good to know, thank you, prasun.

Comment: Please see my answer for workaround

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, it doesn't works on client scripts.

One possible solution is write a suitelet (if you want to stick with client script, otherwise any server side script should just work) for this operation and call the suitelet in your client script using `nalpiRequestURL(YOUR_SUITELET_DEPLOYED_URL)`

You may additionally want to pass the recordId as URL parameter in your suitelet, and then get the recordId from Suitelet using  `request.getParameter(paramName)`

Comment: These are really good suggestions, and like you said in the above comment thread, it's annoying that this isn't specified in the documentation. Thanks again.

Comment: welcome to NetSuite :) you will love the documentation :)

Comment: Ha! Thanks for the laughs :)

Comment: I think you mean RESTlet, not SUITElet.  A Suitelet is a custom UI page/form you load in a browser.  A RESTlet would let you query the URL and get back a response.